# Laravel global query scope throws max function nesting level reached

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to replace a [query scope](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#query-scopes) with a [global query scope](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#global-scopes), but while my query scope works fine the global one causes the following exception:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_ERROR)

Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!
```

here is my global scope `apply()` method

```
public function apply(Builder $builder)
{
    $builder->whereHas('lifetime', function($query)
    {
        $query->whereNested(function($query)
        {
            $query->whereNull('lifetimes.days')
                ->orWhereRaw('NOW() < DATE_ADD(updated_at, INTERVAL lifetimes.days DAY)');
        });
    });
}
```

I just extracted the code in the original query scope and put it here.

The problem is with the `whereHas()` method, its callback never called and if i replaced it with another query building method like a `where('col', 'value')` there would be no error

In fact it indirectly calls `getQuery()` on the model then it is handled with the `Model::__call()` after that the global scopes be called again on the model, including mine and causes never ending recursive calls.

stack frames (starts from up and goes down):

- Model::all()
- Model->newQuery()
- Model->applyGlobalScopes()
- **MyScope**->apply()
- Builder->whereHas()
- Builder->has()
- Relations\BelongsTo->getRelationCountQuery()
- Relations\Relation->wrap()
- **MyModel**->getQuery()
- Model->__call()
- Model->newQuery()
- Model->applyGlobalScopes()
- **MyScope**->apply()
- Builder->whereHas()
  ....

Comment: You can't use `has` methods in a global scope currently. It's a bug, I believe there's an issue on github about it.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk yes, I found it [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues?q=has+global+scope)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have fixed this. [issue on github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/6997)